# Windows dualboot missing efi partition error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub-efi

I currently have Windows 10 LTSC and I tried to install Ubuntu 22 alongside it, but when I was in the step of creating partitions, I had two Windows partitions, probably one for the bootloader, but it was NTFS with around 512mb, and it didn't have "bootloader" or anything like that in the label/desc.

So I just went on and created a swap partition and the rest of the disk as ext4 as usual, then I selected "sda" to install grub but I had an error saying that I didn't have an EFI partition.

I know my BIOS is UEFI, but I don't know if my Windows installation is using an efi partition so I don't know what to do. I don't know if I should create a new one and override Window's (but that would make my Windows unbootable), or just go ahead and take the risk of not having the efi partition or something else. I'm stuck because I don't want to brick my sistem or having to spend hours troubleshooting something that I could have avoided in the first place.

Any advice on what to do? I've been installing Windows the same way forever, so I probably selected the "legacy" option everywhere, but I don't remember.

Comment: How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS, is then how it installs for both Windows & Ubuntu. Best to have both systems in same boot mode, and that is required if both on same drive. If drive is MBR, then Windows is BIOS boot, if drive is gpt then install is UEFI. BIOS install may request an ESP (maybe for future use?) but you can just continue install, if BIOS install & it will work. If UEFI install it will not work and break Windows BIOS boot. If UEFI hardware (since 2012), better to have all systems in UEFI mode. But conversion from MBR to gpt totally erases drive, so good backups required.

Comment: How can I check if I'm currently using BIOS boot on Windows? If that's the case, should I select "sda" for the bootloader in Ubuntu, or should I select the previously 512mb partition from Windows? Thanks for the reply

Comment: BIOS can only boot from MBR, if you install  grub to PBR or partition, it will never boot. Which drive is which. Post this in question above: `sudo parted -l` If the Windows drive shows this: "Partition Table: gpt" then it will be UEFI. If msdos then it has to be BIOS/Legacy/CSM.  CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode  You want to install grub to whatever drive is then the drive you are installing Ubuntu into.  If only one drive and standard SSD or HDD then probably sda. New SSD are NVMe types.

Comment: Boot to USB Live Ubuntu. Then run command: *sudo parted -l*. Post output of that into your question.